# Opening a C++ Framework using XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, frameworks

I am trying to open up a C++ framework that I have downloaded on my computer so that I could follow a tutorial to learn C++. However, I am using XCode, and whenever I try to open the framework using XCode, it says "Could not open file. (/Users/laffytaffy/Downloads/Chili Framework 2016)".

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I could do to get this working? Thanks for your help! By the way, the framework download page is at https://wiki.planetchili.net/index.php/Beginner_C%2B%2B_Game_Programming_Tutorial_0. If you need the tutorial, it should be linked on that page as well.

Comment: I took a quick look at the description of the framework.  It seems to be VERY specific to Windows calls and functions.

Comment: That’s a Windows-specific tutorial – it’s even specifically made for Visual Studio. It will be of no use to you.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!